# Custom ImageView background draw with app:srcCompat

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-support-library

I have a custom ImageView and I am drawing background to it dynamically like:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    p.setColor(SkinHelper.getColor(getContext(), R.color.color_transparent_white));
    canvas.drawPath(hexagon.getPoints(0, 0), p);

    p.setColor(SkinHelper.getColor(getContext(), R.color.color_dark));
    canvas.drawPath(hexagon.getPartPoints(0, 0, (int) mNumericValue), p);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

If I set the image of the imageview in xml like

```
android:src="@drawable/selector_plan_cancel"
```

than everything works well. But I am using the support library, so I want to set the image of the imageView like

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/selector_plan_cancel"
```

and it's not working. What should I do differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to extend `AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView` and keep the `app:srcCompat`.